# Testing for the expected exception message with junit 5

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5

I have a project where I have tests where I deliberately cause a problem and then verify the code responds the way I want it. For this I want to be sure the exceptions not only are the right class but they must also carry the right message.

So in one of [my existing (junit 4) tests](https://github.com/nielsbasjes/yauaa/blob/v5.12/analyzer/src/test/java/nl/basjes/parse/useragent/utils/TestVersionCollisionChecks.java#L76) I have something similar to this:

```
public class MyTests {
  @Rule
  public final ExpectedException expectedEx = ExpectedException.none();

  @Test
  public void testLoadingResourcesTheBadWay(){
    expectedEx.expect(MyCustomException.class);
    expectedEx.expectMessage(allOf(startsWith("Unable to load "), endsWith(" resources.")));
    doStuffThatShouldFail();
  }
}
```

I'm currently looking into fully migrating to junit 5 which no longer supports the [@Rule](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-tips) and now has the [assertThrows that seems to replace this](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.5.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows(java.lang.Class,org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable)).

What I have not been able to figure out how to write a test that not only checks the exception(class) that is thrown but also the message attached to that exception.

What is the proper way to write such a test in Junit 5?

Comment: `assertThrows` returns an exception so you can invoke `getMessage` on the returned instance and make asserts on this message.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since [`Assertions.assertThrows`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.5.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows(java.lang.Class,org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable)) returns instance of your exception you can invoke `getMessage` on the returned instance and make assertions on this message :

```
Executable executable = () -> sut.method(); //prepare Executable with invocation of the method on your system under test

Exception exception = Assertions.assertThrows(MyCustomException.class, executable); // you can even assign it to MyCustomException type variable
assertEquals(exception.getMessage(), "exception message"); //make assertions here
```

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to @michalk and one of my colleagues this works:

```
Exception expectedEx = assertThrows(MyCustomException.class, () ->
    doStuffThatShouldFail()
);
assertTrue(expectedEx.getMessage().startsWith("Unable to load "));
assertTrue(expectedEx.getMessage().endsWith(" resources."));
```